# Pass values to external class from controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, class, payment-gateway

I have a project in codeigniter in which I have to integrate a payment gateway. The payment gateway integration code file is a separate php file. I want to pass some values to the file.

The file looks like the below code(with lots of functions-I reduces to post here)

```
class NetworkonlieBitmapPaymentIntegration 
{
$networkOnlineArray = array('Network_Online_setting' => array(
'MKEY'    => "GgjhJHh467HGGjjj", 
'MID'     => '123456789',                                                               
'amount' => '1000',
'name' => 'ADCB',
'currency' => 'PHP',             
));
}
$networkOnlineObject = new NetworkonlieBitmapPaymentIntegration($networkOnlineArray);
```

I tried to make it as a library and as well as another controller but no luck.

how can I pass values to this file

Comment: Its better create a common functions helper file isnide helpers folder

Comment: I can make the whole file as a helper, then how can I pass the values to the array

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create a seperate common functions helper inside helper folder.

commonfunctionshelper.php

```
<?php
function paymentFun($mkey,$mid,$amount,$name,$currency)
{
    $networkOnlineArray = array('Network_Online_setting' => array(
        'MKEY'    => $mkey, 
        'MID'     => $mid,                                                               
        'amount' => $amount,
        'name' => $name,
        'currency' => $currency,             
    ));
    }
    $networkOnlineObject = new NetworkonlieBitmapPaymentIntegration($networkOnlineArray);
}
?>
```

Now in your Controller load helpers inside your consturctor

ExampleController.php

```
<?php

class User_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('commonfunctions_helper');
    }

    public function check()
    {
        //calling common functions helper
        paymentFun($mkey,$mid,$amount,$name,$currency);
    }
}
```

This is how you can achieve it.

Comment: Uhh... Your helper doesn't return anything.

Comment: whenever I try to make the whole class as a function it returns me error as " unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of file".https://network-international.sharefile.eu/d-s0b52cdf371844358 this is the link for the sample file

Comment: Why "It is better to create a seperate common functions helper"?

Comment: @Akku Make sure you creare only function inside helper, there is no need to create a class and make it complicated. I have thatswhy given demo

Comment: @Jaymin the whole sample file is a class and I created a function inside the class  
class NetworkonlieBitmapPaymentIntegration {
    function paymentFun($mkey,$mid,$amount,$name,$currency)
{
    $networkOnlineArray = array('Network_Online_setting' => array(
        'MKEY'    => $mkey, 
        'MID'     => $mid,                                                               
        'amount' => $amount,
        'name' => $name,
        'currency' => $currency,             
    ));
    }   
}  but it returns error, as "call to undefined function paymentFun

Comment: But I am still telling for common functions you dont need to create a class jst keep the function and ready to use it